# How to synchronize Azure DevOps repo with GitHub repo

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops

I'm working on a personal project and I have it hosted in an Azure DevOps repo because I'd also like to learn a little bit more about how Azure services work.
However, I'd really like to have an exact copy of this repo available on Github because that's where most of my previous projects have been created.
Ideally, I'd like to set up a system so that every time I pushed to any branch in Azure, the entire repository (i.e. all branches, even if they're new) are copied to GitHub automatically.

I've tried looking around at a few different articles, but I haven't been able to get anything to work, likely because I haven't been able to fully understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this azure Pipelines Build and Release extension helps you synchronise one Git Repository with another : Git Tools for Azure DevOps

Create a CI pipeline and set variable `$(Github.PAT)=GitHub` personal access token. Add this task with the following configuration : `https://<GitHub user name>:$(Github.PAT)@github.com/<OrganizationName>/<RepoName>.git`.

[image]

You could also use PowerShell task with script for it and add pipeline variables as secret variable. Name ‘AzureDevOps.PAT’ (with value as your Azure DevOps PAT) and name ‘Github.PAT’ (with value as your GitHub PAT). Please refer  to [Sync Azure Devops repo with GitHub repo](https://dileepveldi.medium.com/sync-azure-devops-repo-with-github-repo-35a958d7784e).