# Is there a way to synchronize (not import) a github.com repo with an Azure Devops repo without using pipelines

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops

I'm aware of
[How to synchronize Azure DevOps repo with GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905170/how-to-synchronize-azure-devops-repo-with-github-repo) ,
https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/git/177/git-sync-repos.html and
https://myownpicloud.wordpress.com/2021/01/20/how-to-synchronize-azure-repos-with-external-git-repos/
on how to configure a pipeline to fetch and push between two different repos.

But I try to fully integrate a github.com repo into Azure Devops: basically only having ONE repo in github and within Azure Devops.

Comment: Not clear what you expect. What is the goal to have 2 repositories (GitHub and ADO)? As ADO could fetch source from a GitHub repo... Otherwise, if you **really need** to have 2 repositories, I think that you could use GitHub Actions to mirror GitHub repository to ADO every times something is pushed. At least, you must express more clearly your expectations...

Comment: Ideally I only want ONE GitHub repo, that's mounted inside Azure Devops. No replica, no syncing: just showing the GitHub repo inside Azure Devops. Goal is to have the best of two worlds, where the repo part is in my eyes definitely better in github

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml